# How do I read the value of kCBAdvDataManufacturerData from the advertisement on iOS using xamarin C#

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, core-bluetooth

I tried many things but this seems to be as close as I can get

```
NSDictionary advertisementData = e.AdvertisementData;
NSString ns_p_mdata = new NSString("kCBAdvDataManufacturerData");
NSObject obj_mdata = advertisementData.ValueForKey(ns_p_mdata);
NSData strMdata = (NSData)obj_mdata;

byte[] result = new byte[strMdata.Length];
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(strMdata.Bytes, result, 0, (int)strMdata.Length);
string test = Convert.ToBase64String(result);
```

However, this does not give me the expected value.

I was using obj_mdata.Description before but this no longer works on iOS 13.x

Comment: https://dev.to/codeprototype/correctly-capture-ios-13-device-token-in-xamarin-1968 `obj_mdata.Description` doesn't work anymore in iOS13 as said in the NSHipster linked article ;)

Comment: that may just be the exact article I need :) :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually those constants that are used as strings in iOS are tucked away somewhere as an enum or get only property.

this one appears to be at `CoreBluetooth.CBAdvertisement.DataManufacturerDataKey`. I think that's the one you're looking for.

Comment: So that's the constant which you can use to get the data, but the data still comes back in a format which is not a string. How do I change it into a string?